# iOS version affecting app download

Tags: ios, swift

I recently submitted an app to the app store and it was approved, however it appears that I'm almost the only one that can download it. I've asked family and friends to download it on their devices but they just get a message saying something along the lines of

"iOS version 8.3 or later is required."

This is clearly a problem because it limits the amount of downloads, is there a way around this to allow users with almost any version of iOS to download the app?

I really appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the *iOS deployment target* in your project build settings

[image: project]

Or set the *deployment target* of each target (general settings).

[image: target]

You should be able to lower down to 7.X with a Swift-written application.

Make sure you don't any API specific to iOS 8.X or that you handle those correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, click on your Xcode project and navigate to the General tab. Under Deployment Info, change your Deployment Target to the oldest OS version you would like to support. You must recompile and make sure to test on different OS versions, as you won't be able to call newer APIs if they don't exist yet in that iOS version.